# Is there a better/shorter way to check a value of an object within an array which is part of an object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm sure this question must have been answered before, so a link (or what specifically to ask Google) would suffice, but what is the best way to do a check in a scenario like this (and does the new `?` operator help in scenarios like this):

```
/**
 * An API returns a job object like:
 * { id: 123, name: 'The Job', details: [ { detail_name: "Foo", some: "thing" }, { detail_name: "Bar", some: "thing else" } ] }
 */

const fooDetail = job.details.find(attr => {
  return attr.detail_name === 'Foo' });
        
if (fooDetail && fooDetail.detail_name === "Foo") {
  // todo process `some: "thing"` 
}
```

It seems long winded to have to `find` an object in an array based on a property, but then having to check again that the object exists before checking the property (or get a `can't get detail_name of undefined` error). Is there a better/shorter way?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

This will return true if one is found..
The same callback as find can be used

```js
const hasDetail = job.details.some(attr => {
  return attr.detail_name === 'Foo' });
        
if (hasDetail) {
  // todo process `some: "thing"` 
}
```

If you're simply want to get the value and then later on check if the property exists, you can use `find` and ?. operator

```js
const addDetail = job.details.find(attr => {
  return attr.detail_name === 'Foo' });
        
if (addDetail?.detail_name === 'Foo') {
  // todo process `some: "thing"` 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do also

```
job.details.forEach(x=>{
    if(x.detail_name == "Foo") {
        console.log(x.some);
    }
});
```